# What are these extra methods in the Selenium Webdriver code?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I record some steps of my website using Selenium IDE and then I Export it using Java /JUnit 4 / WebDriver . And then I open it in my Eclipse  and I find 4 extra methods in my code. I don't really understand the purpose of this methods, as I don't deal with alert windows or finding element.
Here are the methods

```
 @After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try {
  driver.findElement(by);
  return true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  return false;
}
}

private boolean isAlertPresent() {
try {
  driver.switchTo().alert();
  return true;
} catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
  return false;
}
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
try {
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  String alertText = alert.getText();
  if (acceptNextAlert) {
    alert.accept();
  } else {
    alert.dismiss();
  }
  return alertText;
} finally {
  acceptNextAlert = true;
}
```

The last 3 methods are quit easy to understand what it does, but Please someone tell me what tearDown() does. Also is it ok i can just remove these functions and keep only the required part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to keep the `setup()` and `teardown()` methods. The `setup()` method is what is used to start your browser session before running your test, and `teardown()` is used to cleanly exit it when the test has completed.

Answer (score 4):

The `tearDown()` method is used to restablish the state prior to the test. This is why it has the Junit clause `@after`. This function will be called after every test execution in that class. You can also use a `setUp()` method with a `@Before` clause to prepare every test.

The first line of the method: `driver.quit();` closes the browser (aka webdriver). Next ones check if there is a non-empty error string, and if it exists, it makes the test fail.